# How can I map a compactBuffer in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I have a compactBuffer like this :

```
CompactBuffer(((8,1.2),((1,1.3),1)), ((8,1.2),((4,1.1),1)), ((8,1.2),((7,2.1),1)), ((8,1.2),((8,1.2),1)), ((8,1.2),((10,1.1),1)))
CompactBuffer(((12,7.2),((3,5.2),1)), ((12,7.2),((12,7.2),1)))
CompactBuffer(((5,3.1),((2,2.7),1)), ((5,3.1),((5,3.1),1)), ((5,3.1),((6,3.2),1)), ((5,3.1),((9,2.2),1)), ((5,3.1),((11,2.8),1)), ((5,3.1),((13,5.1),1)))
```

How can I map that compactBuffer and pass a function (that I code it) into that map ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

[CompactBuffer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/CompactBuffer.scala) is an optimized mutable collection for holding few items. It implements the `Seq[T]` trait, so all your well-known `Seq` operations can be applied to `CompactBuffer`.

So, to transform the contents of the `CompactBuffer`, a `map` operation should do the trick:

```
val v = CompactBuffer(((12,7.2),((3,5.2),1)), ((12,7.2),((12,7.2),1)))
val transf = v.map(tuple => ... )
```

All other collection operations will also work: `flatMap`, `filter`, `take`, `drop`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean without knowledge of the `CompactBuffer` class, how about this:

```
compactBuffer match {
  case CompactBuffer(data) => yourFunction(data)
}
```